# Convert jbytearray to char* with wrong code in JNI

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I try to convert jbytearray to char* at Jni Layer. However, its result has some wrong character like this:

```
07-23 10:22:43.701 26585-26646/com.zspirytus.androidlua D/ScriptPkgDataFetcher: getPkgData: 0028 at Kotlin
07-23 10:22:43.701 26585-26646/com.zspirytus.androidlua D/LuaEngine: getPkgData: 0028�ض
07-23 10:22:44.221 26585-26646/com.zspirytus.androidlua D/ScriptPkgDataFetcher: getPkgData: 0028 at Kotlin
07-23 10:22:44.221 26585-26646/com.zspirytus.androidlua D/LuaEngine: getPkgData: 0028�ض
07-23 10:22:44.721 26585-26646/com.zspirytus.androidlua D/ScriptPkgDataFetcher: getPkgData: 0028 at Kotlin
07-23 10:22:44.721 26585-26646/com.zspirytus.androidlua D/LuaEngine: getPkgData: 0028�ض
```

At Kotlin Layer, the result in String type is `"0028"`; at Jni Layer, the converted result is `"0028�ض"`. The following is what I do in my code:

At Kotlin, the function return a bytearray:

```
fun getContentByEntryName(entryName: String): ByteArray {
    // data is always a String with value "0028"
    val data = ZipFileUtils.getFileContentFromZipFile(ZipFile(scriptPkg), entryName)
    Log.d("ScriptPkgDataFetcher", "getPkgDatagetPkgData: $data at Kotlin")
    return data.toByteArray()
}
```

At Jni, I convert jbytearray to char* like this:

```
jbyteArray jba = (jbyteArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, methodId, dataPath);
int len = env->GetArrayLength (jba);
char* buff = new char[len];
env->GetByteArrayRegion (jba, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buff));
Log_d(LOG_TAG, "getPkgData: %s", buff);
```

Seem that it is not work correct. I also try this code, but it still not 
 work correct...

```
jbyteArray jba = (jbyteArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, methodId, dataPath);
const char *cStr = (char *) (env)->GetByteArrayElements(jba, NULL);
```

Is any mistake existing in my code? Help me to correct it, Please. Thanks!

Comment: `char* buff = new char[len];` -- This does not null-terminate the string data, which is required for C-style strings to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use `new char[]` to create string data, and then use that data in functions that require null-termination, you have to explicitly add the null terminator.

In addition, you may not have allocated enough space for the terminating null, thus you need to allocate `len + 1` bytes.

You can do this:

```
char* buff = new char[len + 1]();
```

which fills the buffer with null characters or:

```
char* buff = new char[len + 1];
buff[len] = '\0';
```

However I highly suggest you use a `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead of doing things this way.

Since JNI is very fragile, if an exception is thrown, you may get memory leaks using raw pointers this way.

Here is a small routine you can use to convert from a Java byte array to a vector:

```
#include <vector>
//...
jbyteArray jba = (jbyteArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, methodId, dataPath);
int len = env->GetArrayLength (jba);
std::vector<char> buff(len + 1, 0);
env->GetByteArrayRegion (jba, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buff.data()));
Log_d(LOG_TAG, "getPkgData: %s", buff.data());
```

This will not suffer from memory leaks if an exception is thrown, since `std::vector` will automatically deallocate the memory when the vector goes out of scope for any reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it work correctly. I am not familiar with C/C++，how can I convert jbytearray to string or vector?

Comment: Added small routine to convert to vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I try it and it work correctly.